# How to Completely Uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have had Ubuntu on my netbook for a while now but I really need Windows back on my netbook for one of my classes. I have no idea how to uninstall it.

Every way I have seen so far that removes it off my netbook seems to lead me to another problem. My netbook can't read CDs because there is no CD drive. I just bought Windows 7 but all it came with is a code. I really need help. I have Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Welcome Shyanne.  This question has been asked before here.  You will find your answer here  http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download a Windows ISO, and unzip it into a Pendrive.
2. In your netbook BIOS, change the **Boot Order**, and select **USB/Flashdrive** as the **First Boot**.
3. Make a clean install of Windows. It's Highly Recommended to make two partitions, one for Windows, and one for Ubuntu, in case of emergency (to recover files).

   - If you choose this option, first install Windows, and later, install Ubuntu.